# Excel function: Which value is larger

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, is there a native function that will return the larger of two values? I'm looking to avoid using the IF function. I'm using Excel 2010 Beta if that's worth anything.

For example: GTR(66,24) will return 66.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `MAX(Cell1, Cell2)`. It accepts an unlimited number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks guys; having tried this in google sheets and Excel 2013, I think it's worth noting that the arguments to `MAX()` can also be a a mix of cell ranges, constants, arithmetic expressions and function outputs, in addition to single cell references.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Max](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/max.php)

> The MAX function, one of Excel's
>   statistical functions, is used to find
>   the largest or maximum number in a
>   given list of values or arguments.

```
=MAX( argument1, argument2, ... argument30 )
```